# React setState is not re-rendering current values,instead rendering the previous stored value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to re-render my class component with user values , but set state is only rendering the previous value, and then the current value. By which I mean, it is working one step back. Lets say initial value was set to 0. After onclick, i wanted to update the value to 20,but it gave me 0. Now when I try to update to 40, it gives me the value 20. Can someone please help me with the solution and detailed explanation as to why is this happening.
**My Class Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TemperatureRange extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            initialTemperature:0
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(userValue){
        
        this.setState({
            initialTemperature:userValue
        })
        if(this.state.initialTemperature>0 && this.state.initialTemperature<30){
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <input type="number" id="number" />
                <input type="button" id="button" value="Check" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(document.querySelector("#number").value)}}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TemperatureRange from './Components/TemperatureRange'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TemperatureRange/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am confused as to why my state is not updated on click with the present user value. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `setState` function the state isn't changed immediately as  [`setState` is asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous). I suggest moving your effect in the [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) (plus componentDidMount) lifecycle method:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TemperatureRange extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            initialTemperature:0
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(userValue){
        this.setState({
            initialTemperature:userValue
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.state.initialTemperature>0 && this.state.initialTemperature<30){
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.state.initialTemperature>0 && this.state.initialTemperature<30){
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector("#container").style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <input type="number" id="number" />
                <input type="button" id="button" value="Check" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(document.querySelector("#number").value)}}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to avoid that duplicated logic between componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate

Comment: Thank you @HappyDev. The concept of useState is async was not known to me. Now it is making sense why componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate is required and where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Like @happydev already stated, the `setState` method will not change the value immediately, react will first re-render the page, and the value will then be updated.

However, if you are keeping to the class based Components, I would suggest the following solution instead:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TemperatureRange extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            initialTemperature: 0,
            backgroundColor: "red",
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(userValue) {
        const color = userValue > 0 && userValue < 30 ? 'red' : 'green';
        this.setState({
            initialTemperature: userValue,
            backgroundColor: color,
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { backgroundColor } = this.state;
        return (
            <div id="container" style={{ backgroundColor }}>
                <input type="number" id="number" />
                <input 
                  type="button" id="button" value="Check" 
                  onClick={() => {
                   this.handleClick(document.querySelector("#number").value)}
                  }
                 />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This way, your code looks cleaner, I you don't need to access direct HTML DOM elements.
You can go the extra step and create a state for the `number` input, and use the onChange method, but this would out of scope of your question.

In general, `document.querySelector` in most cases, not the "react" way of doing things, I will not go into too much detail here, there are cases where I would maybe get direct HTML elements with `document.querySelector`, but I would 99.9999999% of the time avoid using direct DOM elements, as it contradicts the concepts of react.

Comment: A very unique way and a approach which wasn't known to me. Thanks a lot @Samer Murad.

Comment: I got to be frank here, this is the "react" way of doing things, there is honestly nothing special about it, using `document.querySelector` is very plain JavaScript, and is not a thing that should be done in react, if you haven't encountered this yet, I would guess you are very new to react and come from other libraries. As a rule of thumb, everything done with dom elements, can be done in react without touching the dom elements directly. I would also advice against solutions that incorporates `componentDidUpdate`.  because it tangles your code, and makes certain scenarios really bad

Comment: You really think should read up on states in react and to use them, it will help you get a better understanding of how to use react. Because it really is powerful, but without understanding what you are doing you end up creating a lot of pitfalls for yourself